# Filtro no dplyr com restrição pelo valor máximo de variável do db gapminder

Tags: r

Estou fazendo o filtro no `df`  `gapminder`, gerando um `df` vazio quando utilizo a variável `gdpPercap`:

```
library(gapminder) # versão 0.2.0

library(dplyr)  # versão 0.7.2

gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 2007, gdpPercap==max(gdpPercap)) 

# A tibble: 0 x 6

# ... with 6 variables: country <fctr>, continent <fctr>, year <int>, lifeExp <dbl>, pop <int>, gdpPercap <dbl>
```

Se eu altero a variável da consulta, aparece o resultado esperado

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 2007, pop==max(pop)) 

# A tibble: 1 x 6

# country continent  year lifeExp   pop      gdpPercap

#1   China      Asia  2007  72.961 1318683096  4959.115
```

Seria um *bug* do `dplyr`? Estou usando RStudio (Version 1.0.143) e MRO (3.3.3).

Answer (score 5):

O resultado está correto. O comando

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 2007, gdpPercap==max(gdpPercap))
```

vai te retornar todas as linhas do data frame `gapminder` que ocorreram no `year` de 2007 e cujo `gdpPercap` seja igual ao máximo valor de `gdpPercap`. Acontece que nenhum país satisfaz esta condição. Veja o seguinte:

```
gapminder %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(max(gdpPercap))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
    year `max(gdpPercap)`
   <int>            <dbl>
 1  1952        108382.35
 2  1957        113523.13
 3  1962         95458.11
 4  1967         80894.88
 5  1972        109347.87
 6  1977         59265.48
 7  1982         33693.18
 8  1987         31540.97
 9  1992         34932.92
10  1997         41283.16
11  2002         44683.98
12  2007         49357.19
```

O valor máximo de `gdpPercap` ocorreu em 1957. Assim, não faz sentido perguntar quais países obtiveram este valor em 2007. Perceba que o comando abaixo, com o ano de 1957, retorna um resultado não-vazio:

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 1957, gdpPercap==max(gdpPercap))
# A tibble: 1 x 6
  country continent  year lifeExp    pop gdpPercap
   <fctr>    <fctr> <int>   <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>
1  Kuwait      Asia  1957  58.033 212846  113523.1
```

Se o tu objetivo era encontrar o país com maior `gdpPercap` em 2007, tu deve primeiro agrupar os dados de acordo com o ano:

```
gapminder %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  filter(year==2007, gdpPercap==max(gdpPercap))
# A tibble: 1 x 6
# Groups:   year [1]
  country continent  year lifeExp     pop gdpPercap
   <fctr>    <fctr> <int>   <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>
1  Norway    Europe  2007  80.196 4627926  49357.19
```